# Unity Interception (AOP) slowing down MVC Editor Templates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unity-container, aop

I have recently added Unity Interception to my MVC app, using the following in the bootstrap code:

```
    private static void RegisterProfilingHooks(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        var registrations =
            container.Registrations.Where(m => m.RegisteredType != m.MappedToType).Where(
                m => m.RegisteredType.Name != "IProfilingService").Take(150).ToList();

        foreach (var registration in registrations)
        {
            container.AddNewExtension<Interception>().Configure<Interception>().SetInterceptorFor(
                registration.RegisteredType, new InterfaceInterceptor());
        }

        container.Configure<Interception>()
            .AddPolicy("ProfilerPolicy")
            .AddMatchingRule<NamespaceMatchingRule>(
                new InjectionConstructor(new InjectionParameter("MyApp.*")))
            .AddCallHandler<ProfilerHandler>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    }
```

However, oddly I'm seeing my Editor Templates taking about 2 seconds (before, only milliseconds) to load, per editor template. So a form with 10 elements takes 10 seconds to load.

Basically, this code is just to intercept a profiling handler on all IoC registrations, so that we can profile any methods invoked on these instances.

The problem is not the profiler handler, because this happens even when I comment out the ProfilerPolicy configuration.

It's the foreach loop and the extension wiring that's causing this:

```
foreach (var registration in registrations)
{
    container.AddNewExtension<Interception>().Configure<Interception>().SetInterceptorFor(
        registration.RegisteredType, new InterfaceInterceptor());
}
```

Why would this interception code have this bizarre effect on my Editor Templates?

**Additional info:**

I've ruled out anything in the templates themselves causing this, as I have updated them to be basic passthroughs, and still see the issue. For example, using this as a string template:

```
@model System.String
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m)
```

I still get the same timings.

I don't know if somehow this interception is causing our view searching to drag, or what. That's the only thing left that I can think of at this point. Our view path definitions are pretty straight-forward:

```
AreaPartialViewLocationFormats = new[] {
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Sublayouts/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Renderings/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
    "~/Areas/Global/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
};
```

Comment: It seems like you are adding the interception extension multiple times in the loop. Can't check it now as I don't have compiler at hand but it certainly is not necessary. The question is - could this be the source of your slowdown?

Comment: Very possibly. I'm new to interception, and it's very possible this solution isn't optimal. It's just weird that it only seems to be dragging down our editor templates. Other views and partial views seem unaffected. Thanks so much for your thoughts.

Comment: But basically, we need to register the interception on all registrations, but *after* they've already been loaded (don't want to explicitly add interception, as we want this for all registrations). So not sure how to apply interception to all container registrations without looping through and adding them.

Comment: Just verify whether or not this causes the slowdown by moving the AddNewExtension outside the loop and just configure the interception manually for even a single type. If the slowdown is gone, you will surely have another minor issue of applying the interception easily to all registrations but at least the slowdown will kill you no more.

Comment: Well, there are about 250+ registrations (this is a large, multi-team web site). You can see the `Take(150)` above, that was in effort to see if the number of registrations affected the timings. It seems it does after a point, then they start increasing steadily (not a sudden increase). I don't know why the `AddNewExtension` ended up in the loop -- it was above originally. Trying this to see if it helps.

Comment: Bingo, that was it! Please post this, and I'll accept this as the answer. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are adding the interception extension multiple times in the loop. Can't check it now as I don't have compiler at hand but it certainly is not necessary. The question is - could this be the source of your slowdown?

(Posted as an answer as suggested by the OP after a short discussion)